# Play 2.2 action not processed in parallel with web service response handler

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result action1() {
        WS.url(WS_URL).get().map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return ok();
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result action2() {
        return ok();
    }
}
```

The client first calls `action1()`, then, it calls `action2()`. However, it seems that Play process the second request after those 10 seconds. I thought that responses from web services are processed by Play in separate threads, but it seems that's not true. In this case, what should I do if I want to *sleep* or to execute some code after a timeout, without interrupting the server from serving other requests?

EDIT: this happens when the response from the WS arrives before the client calls action2().

Comment: Are you sure that the client doesn't wait for the action1 to finish before calling action 2? Can you show the client code?

Comment: No, it doesn't wait. Actually, the server returns from action1 immediately after sending the request to the WS, but it seems that the response from the WS is handled by the same thread that handles the actions. I forgot to mention that the response from the WS arrives before the client calls action2.

Answer (score 0):

Play by default allocates the same number of threads as the number of CPU cores you have (although note that there are multiple thread pools), so configure it to allocate more threads if you want to do blocking operations such as `sleep` in  a handler.

Comment: Indeed, the solution I found was to make each WS call in a separate thred, using the Akka system.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but the code below will insert a 10 second delay between when the WS call returns, and when it returns an ok result:

```
public static F.Promise<SimpleResult> action1() {
    return WS.url(WS_URL).get().flatMap(new Function<WS.Response, F.Promise<WS.Response>>() {
        public F.Promise<WS.Response> apply(WS.Response response) {
           return F.Promise.timeout(response, 100000);
        }
    }).map(new Function<WS.Response, SimpleResult>() {
        public SimpleResult apply(WS.Response response) {
           return ok();
        }
    };
}
```

To understand Play's thread pools, read this:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

To understand how Play works with promises, read this:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync

Comment: When the user clicks a button on my site, multiple WS calls are done by the server and the responses returned by these calls are used to update a list of objects. In the meantime, the client sends periodic AJAX requests to check if any of the objects in the list was updated. The problem is that the AJAX requests are served *after* all the WS calls return and not in parallel as I expected. The solution I found was to make each WS call in a separate thred, using the Akka system.

Comment: Were you calling `get()` on the promise returned by the WS API?  If you were, then basically you turned your application into a synchronous blocking application, and the behaviour you were seeing is expected.  Never, ever call `get()` on a promise.

Comment: No, I don't call `get()`.